# What exactly is meant by beta dependence in this fixed bias BJT scheme?

Tags: bjt, biasing

What I understand that, in a fixed bias BJT scheme the problem is beta dependence.

Below is an example from a text:

[image]

Now I read that this is not a good design. But I will still solve this by assuming we have a constant unchanging beta:

So the aim is to obtain around 7.5V(half-rail) at output when there is no small signal input.

I will use beta and write KVL as follows:

I neglect Vbe since it is small relative to the 7.5V; I also take Ie=Ic=100*Ib.

KVL:

Ib * Rb + Ie * Re = 15V or

Ib * Rb + 100 * Ib * Re = 15V

Since we want 7.5V output it means:

Ib * Rb = Ie * Re = 7.5V this yields:

Rb = 100 * Re

Using the KVL equation with this becomes:

Ib * 100 * Re + Ib * 100 * Re = 15V

Re = (15/200) * (1/Ib)

Re = 7.5/Ie

So if we set Ie = 1mA

Re = 7.5k Ohm

Rb = 750k Ohm

Now above assumes beta is known equal to 100 and is fixed and never changes. And I read it is bad design. Now the reason is given as because it is dependent on beta.

But here what is meant by beta dependence? Does that mean two same models have different beta or does that mean beta is changing by time for the same unit?

Comment: This not duplicate at all. Im asking a particular circuit about a specific biasing scheme fixed bias BJT scheme. Your duplicate is a general question. Unbelievable you think this is duplicate Im really discouraged. I will not bother to explain why not duplicate one must be blind to not to see the difference.

Comment: You seem to be asking whether beta can change between two transistors and whether it can change for one transistor over time. Is that not correct? The rest of the question is just explaining why you want to know whether it can change?

Comment: No Im not asking that..

Comment: Then what are you asking? Whether the circuit is a bad design?

Comment: It sounds like you already know the answer to "What exactly is meant by beta dependence?" - it means your circuit works differently depending on beta, i.e. it's dependent on beta.

Comment: Which one is true by "change"?: 1)It means the two units of the same model might have very different betas so when we replace the transistor the quiescent point will change. 2)It means the beta for the same transistor will drastically change by time.

Comment: And the "duplicate" says both of these are true. Did you read it?

Comment: Also, if you take into account that all components change their nominal value in temperature, so the fact that it depends on beta, and you resisitors and BJT changes in temperature it makes it floating. What I mean is that during normal funcitoning it will get hotter and that will change the output you calculated.

Comment: Rearranging your formulae and using your assumptions:  Rb = (Vxx-Ve)x Re/Ve  / Beta. -> Rb is inversely proportional to Beta. Beta for a batch of transistors lies in a range - often with values that differ by 2:1 and sometimes more. Beta varies with age and temperature. Your bias resistor and/or your operating point will be "all over the map".

Comment: No, answer/comment on this subject from @jonk ? I'm disappointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging your formulae and using your assumptions:

- Rb = (Vcc-Ve) x (Re/Ve) x Beta. -> Rb is proportional to Beta.

and/or, re-rearranging

- Ve = (Vcc x Re)/ ( Beta x Rb  + Re) <- Ve is Beta dependant.

Beta values for a batch of transistors often differ by 2:1 and sometimes more.
Beta varies with age and temperature.
Your bias resistor and/or your operating point will be "all over the map".

E&OE - even if I made an error there (which I don't think I did) the point is that
 **the circuit is "undesignable" in real world situations.**

Comment: I think it will be "x Beta " instead of "x 1/Beta" ? (in your last equation)

Comment: @panicattack Yes - should be asleep - 4am here at the bottom of the world. Formulae should be right now. Should.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose beta can vary from part to part from 75 to 150 (2:1), which is practical for normal inexpensive binned Asian transistors. So you design the circuit for a beta of 100. You build a batch of 10,000 pieces and you happen to get some transistors at the extremes.

Ve with nominal beta is 7.15V

Ve with beta of 75 is 6.13V

Ve with beta of 150 is 8.58V

So your maximum swing is reduced a bit for those units at the extremes, but if your required signal levels are not pushing the limits of the supply you're fine. If you're amplifying an AC signal up to (say) 1V you don't much care about the DC voltage at the emitter. You're also going to have to account for beta variation with temperature (and aging, especially at very high temperature, and radiation exposure), which depends on the required operating range, quite significant for military temperature range, relatively modest for consumer products. Maybe you don't care much if that radio starts to distort a bit if someone is operating it at -40°, only that it works well from 10°C to 35°C, and costs the minimum amount.

Whether it's good design or not really depends on the design parameters. You can reduce the bias point variation with temperature to almost any desired amount with the addition of extra circuitry, up to and including using op-amps to force a bias point. It's bad design to make the circuit unnecessarily expensive and complex when something simpler and cheaper will meet all the specifications.

Comment: How are these Ve's being calculated????

Comment: @AJ_Smoothie It was 4 or 5 years ago- I don't recall. Maybe I used a spreadsheet. Do you get different answers?

Answer (score 0):

"
But here what is meant by beta dependence? Does that mean two same models have different beta or does that mean beta is changing by time for the same unit? 
"

Both. There can be a large variation in beta from one unit to another of the same part number, depending on how tightly they are screened during manufacturing. AND, for any one transistor, beta changes significantly with temperature. In your circuit the transistor is dissipating approx. 8 mW.  This is not a lot, but it is enough to change its beta as it warms up.

Beta also changes with time as the transistor ages.

Answer (score 0):

Panic attack - the problem with the shown circuit is the following (and that is the reason, this scheme is not recommeded):

The circuit incorporates something like a contradiction. Let me explain:

- It is the task of the resistor RE to stabilize the DC operating point - mostly against temperature variations. This resistor provides negative **current-controlled VOLTAGE feedback**. Such a feedback scheme works best when the DC base voltage is kept as constant as possible (using a low-resistive voltage divider at the base). Remember that the most severe temperature influence is caused by the temperature sensitive current Is that appears in Shockleys well-known expoenetial expression Ic=Is[exp(VBE/Vt)-1].
- However, in the shown circuit that is not the case. Here, we have a large resistor RB (mostly in the high kOhm or even MegOhm range). Therefore, we speak about "current injection" into the base. And this current is highly dependent on the beta-value which has very large tolerances. This effect cannot be (partly) compensated by voltage feedback (provided by RE).
- When you want to use only one single resistor for DC biasing, implement **voltage-controlled current-feedback** and connect RB not to the power rail but to the collector (of course with a recalculated value). In this case, RE should be removed.